# Disable double click to zoom in feature in plotly js

Tags: javascript, plotly

I was trying with the below code which is given [here](https://plotly.com/javascript/line-and-scatter/).

```
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  y: [1, 6, 3, 6, 1],
  mode: 'markers',
  type: 'scatter',
  name: 'Team A',
  text: ['A-1', 'A-2', 'A-3', 'A-4', 'A-5'],
  marker: { size: 12 }
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5],
  y: [4, 1, 7, 1, 4],
  mode: 'markers',
  type: 'scatter',
  name: 'Team B',
  text: ['B-a', 'B-b', 'B-c', 'B-d', 'B-e'],
  marker: { size: 12 }
};

var data = [ trace1, trace2 ];

var layout = {
  xaxis: {
    range: [ 0.75, 5.25 ]
  },
  yaxis: {
    range: [0, 8]
  },
  title:'Data Labels Hover'
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

I want to disable the default plotly feature double clicking to zoom in the markers. But I want to keep the zoom out feature on double clicking.

Is it anyhow possible?

Answer (score 1):

Please check [this](https://codepen.io/etpinard/pen/XNXKaM). I have used `doubleClick: 'reset'` to fulfill my objective.